# The address of varible of same structures object in two different function is different

Tags: c

i have two functions one is main and another one is display using structures I initialized the variable id and name and when i display the values . the values are different in main and display function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct Person
{
  int id;
  char name[];

};

void display(struct Person p)
{
  printf("\n\n value: \n Id is : %d   And name is: %s  \n ",p.id,p.name);
   printf("Address: \nThe addres in  function of id is %p and name  is %p \n .........  \n",&(p.id),&(p.name));
}

void main()
{
  struct Person p;
  clrscr();
  p.id=2;
  strcpy(p.name,"kunal");
  printf("Values : \n the id is %d and name is %s \n",p.id,p.name);
  printf("Address: \n The addres in main of id is %p and name is %p",&(p.id),&(p.name));

  display(p);
  getch();
}
```

Output:

Values :

the id is 2 and name is kunal

Address:

The addres in main of id is FFEA and name is FFEC

value:

Id is : 2   And name is: kunal

Address:

The addres in  function of id is FFDE and name  is FFE0

Comment: `name` has zero size, you can't copy anything there.

Comment: well, obviously you can, but the behavior when doing so **is undefined**. An array without a size in a `struct` is only allowed as the very last member, called a *flexible array member*, and only makes sense when dynamically allocating this `struct` with `malloc()`, adding the size for the array manually.

Comment: also, unrelated, *stop using `conio.h` now!* -- it's a thing from the past. If you need "console" control, use `curses.h` for portable code (there are libraries providing it for many systems). If on the other hand, all you want is `clrscr()` -- think about just dropping it.

Comment: Post your output as text. There is no reason to go off site to help you

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: you need add #include<string.h> in order to use str functions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This specific code maybe. But in general it can lead to nasty errors.

Comment: That's common, but not certain, @MadPhysicist.  Since C99, the expression that denotes the function being called needs to have an appropriate pointer-to-function type, and that is *not* established implicitly.  Even calls to functions that do have in-scope declarations can be erroneous if those declarations do not provide prototypes.  Thus, it is at best unhelpful to nitpick whether `#include`ing the appropriate library headers is strictly speaking *needed*.

Comment: In fact, @EugeneSh., since `name` is a flexible array member, when it is accessed by `.` or `->`, it behaves as if it is as large as the size of the host struct minus its offset within the struct (given that the struct here is automatically allocated).  That could be zero, but it also could easily be large enough to accommodate the data being written into it.  The OP's code is quite possibly just fine in that regard, though that depends on how the implementation lays out the struct.

Comment: I have edited it  specifying the char array size but now the values are same for variables but the address of variables are different in main and display function...any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The same can be said about any underallocated array, that it might get somehow padded by the compiler and "allow" overflowing. When using flex member the programmer has to explicitly allocate the space required for it.

Comment: No, @EugeneSh., flexible array members are subtly but importantly different in this regard.  The standard explicitly specifies that when one of them is accessed via a member-access operator, "it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed" (C11 6.7.2.1/18).  The portable and safe way to ensure that there is enough space is to allocate the object dynamically, but if the struct is naturally large enough then accessing it is well-defined even for automatically allocated objects.

Answer (score 1):

In this structure declaration:

> ```
> struct Person
> {
>   int id;
>   char name[];
> };
> ```

, the `name` member is a so-called "flexible array member".  This is not what you want for your purpose, especially because

> In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored.

([C2011 6.7.2.1/18](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18))

The exceptions have to do with accessing the flexible array member via the `.` or `->` operator.  Passing a structure to a function by value, as you are doing, is *not* one of the exceptions.  So yes, the function does not receive the member.  Additionally, it is possible, but not certain, that your `main` invokes undefined behavior when it copies data into `name`, as a result of overrunning the bounds of the structure (the structure could be large enough to accommodate the data you're writing, but that's not guaranteed).

You could make your code work with the structure declaration as it now stands by making sure to allocate the original structure (dynamically) with enough space for the intended contents of the `name` member, and by passing a pointer to it instead of passing it by value.  But that's surely a lot more trouble than it's worth, and it is somewhat specific to this case, as a structure can have at most one flexible array member.

Surely what you really want to do instead is declare the `name` member with a size.  This is how C requires you to declare arrays, with flexible array members being the sole exception.  (Function parameters are *not* an exception, though they may seem to be.  That's a different story.)  If you declare `name` with a size, then your code should work fine:

```
struct Person {
  int id;
  char name[20];
};
```

Of course, that limits you to the specified size.  If you want to be more adaptible then you can declare `name` as a `char *`, and then point it to large enough dynamically allocated space.  This is much more common and more broadly applicable than flexible array members, but it's probably overkill for your exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Just added the size for array in your code, it has fixed size during compile time.

Don't use `conio.h` that is very old.

[conio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)

> conio.h is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide
>   console input/output. It is not part of the C standard library or ISO
>   C, nor is it defined by POSIX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
};

int main() 
{
    struct student record = {0}; //Initializing to null

    record.id=1;
    strcpy(record.name, "No one");

    printf(" Id is: %d \n", record.id);
    printf(" Name is: %s \n", record.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ...I forgot to add the size ....and yes its working as the contents displayed are same but the address aren't same for both the variables of structures

Comment: Sorry i forgot to update ...the two variable address will be different as they are fomal and actual paramaters.